# Determine which columns match search criteria

Tags: mysql

I'm in the process of creating a search on a web system that I'm working on. The search query is quite simple in terms of finding the data that I need however (and I'm not sure if this is possible) I'd like to know **where** the data matched.

```
SELECT o.*, c.`customer_name`
FROM `orders` o
    LEFT JOIN `customers` c ON (o.`customerID` = c.`customerID`) 
WHERE ((o.`orderID` like '%adam%') OR 
    (o.`order_ref` like '%adam%') OR 
    (c.`customer_name` like '%adam%') OR 
    (c.`address_line1` like '%adam%') OR 
    (c.`address_line2` like '%adam%') OR 
    (c.`town` like '%adam%') OR 
    (c.`city` like '%adam%') OR 
    (c.`postcode` like '%adam%'))
```

So in the above query, the customer name could match, but how do I know which column actually matched in the query? Surely this is possible because I'm sure that PhpMyAdmin adds an orange box around the criteria that matches.

I've spent a fairly large amount of time searching but I cannot find a solution possibly because I'm not searching the right terminology. The closest that I've found but still cant really fit into this scenario is using a `CASE WHEN` statement.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Adam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT o.*, c.customer_name,
        CASE WHEN o.orderID LIKE '%adam%' THEN 'orderID'
             WHEN o.order_ref LIKE '%adam%' THEN 'order_ref'
             ...
             WHEN c.postcode LIKE '%adam%' THEN 'postcode'
        END AS which_column_matched
FROM ...
```